# How can I modify header when using tbl_svysummary so the N = N unweighted excluding missing value ? (Survey design object)

Tags: r, header, survey, gtsummary

I'm trying to do a table with `tbl_svysummary()`.
It is asked to have percentage weighted and the N unweighted. My NA values have no interest so I omit them, but my problem is the argument `{N_nonmiss_unweighted}` doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
pcv_s %>%
  tbl_svysummary(include = (langue_eng), 
                 missing = "no", 
                 label = list(langue_eng = "Maîtrise de l'anglais"),
                 statistic = all_categorical() ~"{n_unweighted} ({p}%)") %>%
  modify_header( label = "Anglais :", 
                 stat_0 = "**N = {N_nonmiss_unweighted} **") %>%
  modify_footnote(update = list(everything() ~ NA))
```

and here's the error.

> ✖ There was an error processing column "stat_0"--likely a glue syntax error.
> ℹ The following fields are available to insert via glue syntax:
> column (), N (), N_unweighted (), n (), p (), n_unweighted (), p_unweighted (), level ()
> Error in `map2()`:
> ℹ In index: 2.
> ℹ With name: stat_0.
> Caused by error:
> ! Error processing `modify_*()` for column 'stat_0'.

I tried this and at the end I decided to use sum() typing manually the value, which is not a good solution as I have to do many tables.

I'd like to have N = total observations without missing values.

Comment: please share a reproducible example so others can help

Comment: `modify_header` doesn't support `N_nonmissing_unweighted`, perhaps because the number of missing values will often vary.  It looks like you need to use `add_n`

Comment: Thank you! I will try this one. I'm sorry for the reproducible example missing I've just learnt about pretex and I'm still trying to figure out how to use it properly...